# Accept a check on my behalf in USA, and then transfer the money to me in Europe

Tags: money-transfer, check, international-transfer, paypal

I live in Europe, and I work with a client from USA. Currently he is only able to pay via check, so now I am looking for some way to get paid.

Best way would be to have a relative or a close friend living in USA to accept that check, and then wire transfer the money to me, or using PayPal, TransferWise or something else.

Since I don't have such a person, I am looking for some other way to cash in that check in USA, and have the money being transferred to me in Europe.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a large company that you have dealt with before and with a track record of paying bills, or a company where you don't know anything about them and they approached you to do work? Have you visited their offices?

Comment: Didn't you make agreements on about how to get paid before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some suggestions.

First ask your bank if it is possible to accept a cheque in US dollars. Some won't but some will,  possibly for a fee.

Second ask your bank if there is an account you can open that would take a US dollar cheque. Lots of banks can set those up, again possibly for a fee. Try another bank in your country off they won't. This is your most likely solution.

Third ask the company if they can write a cheque in your home currency.

Fourth ask the company if they can write a money order instead if a cheque. They are similar enough that they might.

Fifth investigate what it takes to open an account in the US. If you are doing a lot of this it might be worth it. Your bank can probably help with this. They have partners and probably branches in the US.

Only then think about the process you are describing. It's going to be complicated so best to avoid it. You would need to get the cheque sent to you, endorsed, sent back, paid in, and then transferred.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
While the above are my recommendations for dealing with a legitimate business, OPs second comments set off all my scam alarms. No bank recommends that a customer not use Paypal, and nothing the company says explains why they don't use a wire transfer, the obvious and simplest way of paying you. **What they write is what a classic scammer says as to why they want to use the most easily forged method of payment in the world.**

Unless this is either a large, reputable company or a company you have dealt with before I strongly recommend:

1. Tell the company that if they insist on paying by cheque you will not be sending them the work until one month after the cheque reaches your account. Tell them that it will take a month for the cheque to process, and a further month to verify that it is valid. (The extra month is because a cheque clear doesn't mean it won't later be discovered to be a forgery -- see many other questions on this site for more details.)
2. Tell the company they can have their work much sooner if they send you payment by wire transfer or another secure method. It's their choice.
3. The stronger they argue that cheque is the only option and you MUST send the work immediately the more certain you can be that this is a scam.
4. **Do not under any circumstances send them money**, even if they 'overpay' you or claim to need some sort of fee to enable your payment.
5. Mentally prepare yourself for the possibility that you will not be paid.

Comment: Very complicated indeed. My client can only pay with check now, and I don't know what to do. Let me paste the response he gave me in the next comment, as I don't quite understand the reasons behind it

Comment: "I was warn by my bank not to use my card on Paypal or any other merchant again because they double remit my account twice before and I don't want to go against my bank warning to me and I wish i can be able to wire the funds to you but am very busy here and don't have time to do all that so in view of this my account manager can only send check to you on my behalf, I tried to persuade him but he said that he is out of options for now."
- my client

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Sounds like they don’t want to pay you at all.

Comment: @PeterK. It's not like I will deliver the project if I don't get paid. This also sounds very stupid and shady to me, but I don't know anything about US banking

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't want to try to turn in the cheque in my country, because the process takes more than a month

Answer (score 5):

There is a common scam: You have a client that can only pay be cheque. You do work for them, send a bill for $5,700 and they accidentally send a cheque for $7,500. Easy enough mistake to make, so they ask you to bank the cheque and send back the $1,800.

You may be clever enough not to lose the $1,800, but you’ll never get paid for your work.

If it’s not clear: they don’t care about the work you do. It’s only the preparation for a scam.

Comment: Ironically, OP's proposed solution is also the setup for a scam. "I need someone to cash this check for me and send the money by wire."

Comment: "I am a Nigerian prince, and I will process your cheque for you in the US and send you the proceeds for a small advance fee...". Would that make three cascading scam setups?

Comment: @DJClayworth "_I am the sugar-baby of a Nigerian prince... if you send me something nice, I will send you one of the cheques he processes for someone in the US..._"

Comment: "My online girlfriend, who is the sugar baby of a Nigerian prince who processes cheques, needs two thousand dollars to come to the US so that she can bring me one of the cheques the prince has given her and live happily with me for ever".

Comment: "... and my friend, who is in the Air Force and is deployed overseas, has the vehicle in Military Storage, but the Air Force will ship it to you once you send the check..."